# Defining the concept of $p-$ value in one or two sentences

Tags: probability, statistics

> Define the concept of $p-$ value in one or two sentences.

P value is the probability of getting the observed or more extreme values when the null hypothesis is true. A small p value is the strong evidence against the null hypothesis , and we reject the null hypothesis. In other words p value is the probability of getting the difference between expected and observed more than calculated when the null hypothesis is true.

I would want you to check out whether or not I'm wrong.

Wishing my kindest regards!

Comment: Pretty good. (+1)  Maybe should say 'more extreme (in the direction or directions of the alternative)' to clarify how p-value is computed for one and two-sided alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You have the gist of it and there is nothing wrong although the wording could be improved some. Instead of saying "a small p value is strong evidence" say a p value less than the chosen level of significance is reason to reject the null hypothesis and is strong evidence etc..The last sentence is a little awkwardly stated.  How about.......

In other words the p value is the probability of getting the observed value based on an expected value from a true null hypothesis.